# Exception after Phone Call from app c# Windows 8.1 Silverligth

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient, phone-call

I have this code here to use the phone dialer to make a simple phone call:

```
 private void buttonMakeCall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
        string number = textBoxCal.Text;
        phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = number;
        phoneCallTask.Show();
    }
```

When I tap the button, the app shows me the dialer—but at the same time I get an exception, from I don't know where.

I've alredy tried to put the code in a *try-catch* ; but, I still always get the exception (the capability I activated).

The exception is this:

> $exception    {"Type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass' cannot be
>   serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the
>   type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public
>   members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be
>   required."} `System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException`

**EDIT** 
Update: I get the exception only after the login (with HTTPClient), on the login page i don't get the exception, really don't what to do, maybe i caused by the connection that is stil on ?

Comment: What is the error/exception?

Comment: Did some cleanup and formatting improvements.

Comment: Yes, but nothing i still get the exception.